# AWS S3 ACLs across accounts

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I have two AWS accounts: A and B (viewable from https://console.aws.amazon.com/organizations). I have given an S3 bucket in account A a policy that allows account B to do everything in that bucket. When I have an EC2 instance on account B upload a file to that bucket, however, account A cannot access it because the owner is account B.

Is there a way of resolving this without having account B specify an ACL that includes account A for every upload?

Answer (score 3):

No.  The account that uploads an object into a bucket owns the object.  All the bucket owner account can do, unless granted permission by the object owner account, is delete the object.